# Sharing lan connection over wifi

Tags: windows, lan

I am trying to share a lan connection of an ENET cable connected to a vehicle and a laptop, to another pc over Wifi so I can access the vehicle connection online with the second pc.

I have tried many programs like usb redirector and other programs but nothing worked, I have also tried team viewer vpn but it also didn't workout.
Thanks in advance